# How to remove hiberfil.sys

Tags: windows-7, power-management, hibernate

I have a small SSD and I want to reclain the space currently used by the hiberfil.sys (~4GB) by disabling hybernation or perhaps preferably, move it to an HDD.

I see under "power Options" that "Sleep/Hibernate After" is set to "Never", yet I have this 4 GB hiberfil.sys file.

I don't see any other options pertaining to Hybernation.

how do I remove this file and keep it from coming  back or relocate it to another drive, an HDD where I would not mind the frivelous writes to take place.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

open an administrator command shell (cmd.exe or powershell.exe) and type:

```
% powercfg -h off
```

and then reboot

Comment: Thanks. I would prefer to move the hybernate file rather than turn it off but it looks looks like it has to be on teh same drive as your OS.

Comment: @Chadworthington: hiberfil.sys can't be moved, since NTLDR uses it before it knows where the registry is, while drive letter assignments are stored in the registry.

Comment: Worked for me without reboot. (Windows 7 SP1 x64)