# Delete hiberfil.sys on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, hibernate, administrator, thinkpad

Ok, so I know what hiberfil.sys is, and I want to use hibernation on my laptop.

But I have another hard drive active in my laptop, it's taken from my old one... and I want to get rid of the hiberfil.sys on that drive. But even with admin privileges I can't delete it.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you disabled hibernation when you try to delete the old hiberfil.sys?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove hiberfil.sys](http://superuser.com/questions/148309/how-to-remove-hiberfil-sys)

Comment: **Closevoters**: this should **not** be closed as a duplicate of [How to remove hiberfil.sys](http://superuser.com/questions/148309/how-to-remove-hiberfil-sys) because this post has **10x** the views and almost twice the upvotes of the proposed duplicate.

Comment: There are zero close votes on this question, and the linked question, is closed as a duplicate of this question so this question literally cannot be closed as a duplicate of the question you point out

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I wanted to do this in the easiest way possible, especially without rebooting.

Open a command prompt as administrator and go to the disk where hiberfil.sys resides. In my case:

```
C:\Windows\System32\> e:
```

In e:, check for hidden files:

```
E:\> dir /A:H
```

In the listing hiberfil.sys should show up. If so, delete it:

```
E:\> del /AS hiberfil.sys
```

I have to warn you: I don't know what happens if you do this with an active hiberfil.sys file. In my case it was on an old hard disk drive and was no longer needed.

Comment: Awesome, I was afraid I'd never reclaim that space from my second drive.  Couldn't use ATTRIB -S on it so was stuck.

Comment: awesome indeed, attrib -h -r -s hiberfil.sys doesn't seem to work, however del /AS hiberfil.sys did the job for me, when trying on an unbootable Windows 10 machine from the command-line opened using Windows 10 installation media

Answer (score 27):

To delete restore file you can open command prompt with admin privileges and run command

```
powercfg -h off
```

Then reboot, and Windows should automatically delete your `hiberfil.sys`. If it doesn't, you can remove it manually.

Then running

```
powercfg -h on
```

restores sleep and hibernate functionality.

You can start command prompt with admin privileges by starting command prompt (<kbd>Windows Key</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> (Run), type `cmd`) and then right-clicking command prompt icon on task bar and selecting "Run as administrator".

Comment: This works! At least on Windows 7 the file is deleted immediately, without needing a restart.

Comment: Confirm what @PeterMortensen mentioned: works without restart!

Answer (score 4):

If you really, really want to get rid of the file, you can always boot to something like a Linux or Windows PE boot disk, and then delete it.

If it was placed there by the current OS, it will come right back. However, from your wording, it sounds like it was placed on the old HD by an old OS that was on it.

Comment: i would've done that, but there is a small problem ;) i am on a thinkpad and those laptops have a so called ultra bay, where (in normal config) your dvd-rom is located. the feature is, that you can slide your dvd-rom out and replace it with (in my case) a frame that holds a harddrive.

Comment: What about booting to a USB device, such as a flash drive or USB DVD drive?

Comment: Don't do it this way. Use the method outlined by @Olli below.

Comment: @user3463 - Why not?

Answer (score 0):

For forcing remove of hibernation file and mounting it use this:

```
sudo mkdir /media/Windows
sudo ntfs-3g -o remove_hiberfile <device> /media/Windows
sudo umount <device>
sudo mount <device> <mountpoint>
```

Instead of `<device>` use the correct device like /dev/sda4

**Update**

Sorry, I don't know why, but I thought you want to mount it on linux.

So, for removing it you can use a Live-CD, like ubuntu, and execute these command above.

Comment: And you expect `sudo`, `mount`, `umount`, and `/dev/sda4` to work *on Windows*?

Answer (score -1):

**Right click the drive**, click **Properties**, and go to the **Security** tab.

Use the **Edit** button to give **Full control** to Users and Authenticated Users.

After that, you should be able to delete the file via the command prompt (make sure that you're using the correct current directory):

```
del /f hiberfil.sys
```

That should get rid of the file. I recommend changing the permissions back afterwards.

[image]